# Can anyone help me fix this m2e-jdt/jdt bug?

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse, m2e, eclipse-jdt

**Introduction**

I have spend a lot of time to fix this [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=388541)

In our application we have a lot of generated code by cxf and jaxb which produces tons of warnings. We use the maven-build-helper plugin to add this code to our projects automatically. 
By adding [this enhancement](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=220928), eclipse JDT enabled the possibility to set the javac -nowarn flag for specific source folders. Unluckily, by updating the maven project the flag gets lost. There are a few threads on SO where users got bugged by bug.

**What I have tried so far**

So i came up with a clever solution, javac has a nowarn flag. I set it to my maven-compiler-plugin and specified the directory. My maven build was fine, but my eclipse build wasn't. My research told me, that eclipse jdt does only use the maven-compiler-plugin source and target version. So my next step was to try to configure the EclipseCompiler, but this is not possible, because there is no possibility to add custom compiler Arguments in eclipse JDT.

Next Step. Inside of the .classpath file, eclipse JDT adds an ignore_optional_problems attribute for each ignored path. By updating the maven project inside of eclipse, this entry gets lost. So i started to write a maven "ignore-source-folder" plugin which should add the missing attribute. To run the plugin each time eclipse starts a build, i also created a m2e connector to refresh the .classpath file and everything should be fine. 
By testing my plugin with my connector i realized, it works, but only 70% of the repetitions.

What happened?

Every time eclipse m2e/Jdt starts a new build, all classpath entries will be removed and populated again. When my maven plugin gets triggered by eclipse, a race condition starts.

So I started to analyze the code of jdt and m2e jdt. The ignore_optional_problems flag gets only once set manually inside of the [patch](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git/commit/?id=3c0e36f85d5a39b357d2b784e0d14acac5614f0c) which was provided to JDT and isn't stored somewhere else. By triggering a new build via m2e-jdt this information gets lost.

**How to fix this problem**

To fix this problem, some element has to be added or extended in jdt which contains all ignored folders. If a new build gets triggered and the classpath file gets newly generated by m2e-jdt this element should be checked for ignored paths. ClasspathEntryDescriptor seems to be a good place for it.

**My problem**

I checked out jdt and m2e jdt, but i have tons of errors inside of my IDE and i have no idea how to start. And even if I fix the code, I have no idea how to build and test it. I think my effort will be to high and we talk about 20 or 30 simple lines of code.

I am afraid if I add my results to the filed bug at eclipse, no one will care about it.

So, is there any developer able and willing to help me for this tiny job?

Comment: Is there any possibility to set a workspace or eclipse-wide exclude for optional_compiler_problems? For example, suppressing those warnings for all target/generated-sources/**/*.java files would be sufficient...

Comment: I've tried it. Unluckily it seems impossible to set custom properties for EclipseCompiler in jdt.

Answer (score 1):

You need to "fix" the M2E's JDT [project configurator](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_project_conversion_enhancements). Probably somewhere in the [m2e-core project](http://git.eclipse.org/c/m2e/m2e-core.git/tree/org.eclipse.m2e.jdt/src/org/eclipse/m2e/jdt/AbstractSourcesGenerationProjectConfigurator.java). So, your change should obtain some kind of configuration flag from the project pom and create corresponding classpath entries for JDT.